# Preg Callback Issue

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

Great Mates...
I need your help.. please let me know why this code is not getting in to the callback function...

```
  wppp_content_hook('<p><a href="http://localhost/work/Kate/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/amg_sls_01.jpg"><img width="300" height="250" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-195" title="amg_sls_0" alt="" src="http://localhost/work/Kate/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/amg_sls_01-300x250.jpg"></a></p>');

  function wppp_content_hook($content) {

    $fileTypes        = array('\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png');
    $pattern          = array();
    $rel              = 'wp-prettyPhoto';
    $pattern[]        = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([A-Za-z0-9\/_\.\~\:-]*?)($fileTypes)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
    $pattern[]        = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([A-Za-z0-9\/_\.\~\:-]*?)($fileTypes)('|\")(.*?)(rel=('|\")".$rel."(.*?)('|\"))([ \t\r\n\v\f]*?)((rel=('|\")".$rel."(.*?)('|\"))?)([ \t\r\n\v\f]?)([^\>]*?)>/i";


    return  preg_replace_callback($pattern,'_regexCallback',$content);
  }

  function _regexCallback($matches) {
   echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
   echo "</pre>";  
    global $post;
    $fileTypes        = array('\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png');
    $rel            = 'wp-prettyPhoto';
    $pattern        = array();
    $replacement    = array();
    $pattern[]      = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([A-Za-z0-9\/_\.\~\:-]*?)($fileTypes)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
    $pattern[]      = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([A-Za-z0-9\/_\.\~\:-]*?)($fileTypes)('|\")(.*?)(rel=('|\")".$rel."(.*?)('|\"))([ \t\r\n\v\f]*?)((rel=('|\")".$rel."(.*?)('|\"))?)([ \t\r\n\v\f]?)([^\>]*?)>/i";
    $replacement[]  = '<a$1href=$2$3$4$5$6 rel="'.$rel.'[g'.$post->ID.']">';
    $replacement[]  = '<a$1href=$2$3$4$5$6$7>';

    return !strpos($matches['0'], '_blank')? preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$matches['0']) : $matches['0'];
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Just saying *here is the code, tell me what is wrong* is neither nice nor helpful.

Comment: No didn't get error..but not it dosn't do anything..

Comment: if you can send any alternative that would be great aswell..

Comment: When do you expect _regexCallback to be called? There's no reference to it in your code.

Comment: You are never calling `_regexCallback` anywhere and you are using `preg_replace` and not `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Sorry Mates,, i have updated the code.. please look into it again..

Comment: Hey, Guys... got something..? please let me know.. i will great thankfull to you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `$pattern` does not match `$content`

Look precisely at your actual regexps by `var_export`'ing `$pattern`

Callback will only be executed if your content will be matched by regular expression. No reason to execute callback function otherwise since there are no matches.

Part of your actual regex:
`([A-Za-z0-9\\/_\\.\\~\\:-]*?)(Array)`

It seems like not desired "Array" sneaked into your pattern (both of them).